# Deriving unit-counit identities

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Assume that $\textrm{C}$ and $\textrm{D}$ are categories and $F\colon \textrm{C}\to \textrm{D}$ and $G\colon \textrm{D}\to \textrm{C}$ adjoint functors, i.e. $F\dashv G$. My definition of *adjunction* is given in terms of the universal property: there exists a natural transformation (unit) $\eta\colon 1\to GF$ such that for all objects $X$ in $\textrm{C}$, for all objects $Y$ in $\textrm{D}$ and for all arrows $f\colon X\to G(Y)$ there exists a unique arrow $f'\colon F(X)\to Y$ such that $G(f') \ \eta_X =f$. Equivalently, we can reformulate it en terms of the counit $\epsilon$.

Now assume that $F\dashv G$ with fixed unit and counit $\eta$ and $\epsilon$. I want to prove that for all object $Y$ in $\textrm{D}$ we have $$G(\epsilon_Y)\circ\eta_{GY}=1_{GY}.$$

I am having trouble to prove that identity, using only the definition above... Can you give me a hint?

Comment: The definition that you use mentions explicitly only $\eta_X$. What is $\epsilon_Y$? Well, that's your $f'$ when $f = 1_{GY}$.

Comment: But assume that $\epsilon$ is another counit (i.e. it satisfies the dual universal property stated above), not necessarily the one corresponding to $f=1_G$. Then, I think that the identity above is still true no?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the definition you want to use does not involve any units and counits. But starting from it, you may show that your universal morphisms $\eta_X$ define a natural transformation $Id_\mathcal{C} \Rightarrow GF$, and then $\epsilon_Y$ may be recovered as $(1_{GY})'$.

Comment: I don't see you point. What I actually mean with counit is a natural transofrmation $\epsilon$ with the universal property. I think that $\epsilon$ doesn't have to be unique and therefore, it may not be equal to $(1_{GY})'$.

Comment: $\epsilon$ has to be unique. Also, when you say, $F\dashv G$ is given with fixed *unit* and *counit*, I think, their connecting identities are *implicitly assumed*.

Comment: @Zakzha J. A fixed adjunction has uniquely defined unit and counit. When you use the definition with universal arrows $\eta_X$, it is equivalent to specifying an adjunction, and $\epsilon_Y$ is *determined* by the identity you are trying to prove. If you just consider separately some arrows $\eta_X$ that satisfy your universal property and an unrelated family of arrows $\epsilon_Y$ that satisfy a similar universal property, then they indeed might come from different adjunctions and not be a unit-counit pair. Which is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ were determined uniquely up to natural isomorphism, I didn't know that there were unique indeed.